# How to preserve user input data when Jeditable ajax post fails

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable in order to post some textarea data to the server. When an ajax post fails for some reason (network problem, server error etc.) it is necessary to leave the form visible and preserve the data that user has entered. Is it possible to do that thing with Jeditable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have jeditable, but by reading their documentation it appears you need to override their onerror event.

```
onerror: function (settings, original, xhr) {
var error = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
//original.reset(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Just tested your snippet with jeditable and found out that resetting original object does not make sense in onerror callback since at that time my text box with user entered data already removed and progress indicator text is displayed instead of it.